# Strange strsplit behavior in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to test a simple script with R language in order to take input from stdin as below:

```
1. #! /usr/bin/env Rscript    
2. line <- readline(prompt("Enter:"))
3. fields <- unlist(strsplit(line, "\t"))
4. key <- fields[1]
5. value <- as.character(fields[2])
6. print(list(city.key, page.value), stdout())
```

And I get the result here:

```
Enter:MohamadAli\t/Boxing
[[1]]
[1] "MohamadAli\\t/Boxing"

[[2]]
[1] NA
```

If I directly input like this:

```
2. line <- "MohamadAli\t/Boxing"
```

I get the expected result as following:

```
[[1]]
[1] "MohamadAli"

[[2]]
[1] "/Boxing"
```

Anyone can help me to explain the difference between the two cases. Why can I not to take the expected output with the input come from stdin.
many thank in advance.

Comment: Did you enter a literal tab character (key pressed) at the `Enter:` prompt, or did you just type in `\t`?  If the latter, then it would be interpreted as a literal backslash followed by a `t`.

Comment: 1. `line` is a reseverd function name. Dont use `line`: 2. `strsplit(lineVar, "\\t")` use double escapement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is there any way to enter literal tab from console? I just typed {\t}

Comment: I don't know if it's possible from R console.  If you were running R in console mode from something like Bash, then yes, it should be possible.

Comment: @AndreElrico: I tried with double escapement and I saw the same problem

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's not availble in R console

Comment: have you also tried  `"\\\\t"`. Four escapes?